# add values of array in php

Tags: php, arrays, yii2-advanced-app, addition

Hi i know its very simple but im stuck in this.
Im fetching data by using join from database.. Now i got the values in array. i want to add these two value in a variable.
Code is below..

```
$sql = "SELECT event_details.max_team_size FROM booking_details INNER JOIN event_details on booking_details.subcategory_id=event_details.id WHERE booking_details.`booking_id` = ".$booking_id." ";

        $command = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql);
        $array = $command->queryAll();
```

`$array` has got the values like this..

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [max_team_size] => 6
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [max_team_size] => 8
    )
 )
```

I want to add these two `max_team_size` into a single variable and use that later to compare.

Comment: By add you mean by `sum` of these two variables or concat

Comment: do you want it in single array?

Comment: @urfusion sum of these two max_team_size values.. like 6+8= 14 in a $total.

Comment: @ChetanAmeta No not in array

Comment: @SalmanRiyaz ok, check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sum = 0;
foreach($array as $data){
    $sum  += $data->max_team_size;
}
echo $sum;
```

Answer (score 1):

Sum you can get from SQL also by using `SUM` function

```
SELECT SUM(event_details.max_team_size) FROM booking_details...
```

In Yii the solution will be

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(event_details.max_team_size) as total FROM booking_details INNER JOIN event_details on booking_details.subcategory_id=event_details.id WHERE booking_details.`booking_id` = ".$booking_id." ";
$command = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql);
$array = $command->queryRow();
```

In PHP to sum particular key in single array you can convert it to single array by using [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function and then use sum function

```
$array = array_column($array, 'max_team_size');
$total = array_sum($array);
```

Note: array_column will work PHP >= 5.5, for PHP < 5.5 you can use foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

Define an empty array like this:

```
$maxArr = array();
```

You can run a foreach loop for your array now and add variable.
Like this:

```
foreach($gotArr as $key=>$val){

}
```